# How to pass images to a NewViewController from ScrollView with Page Control in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to make the images clickable and pass them to a new view controller with more details. I am using UIScrollView with UIPageController inside my HomeViewController.
I was trying to research but couldn't find any specific examples. I am thinking maybe pass it with segue but I can't figure out how. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance. This is my code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet var topScrollView: UIScrollView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pageScrollView()

   }

func pageScrollView() {

    self.topScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.topScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer())

    self.topScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
    let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.topScrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.topScrollView.frame.height


    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "img1")        
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "img2")
    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*2, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "img3")
    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*3, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "img4")
    let imgFive = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*4, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgFive.image = UIImage(named: "img5")


    self.topScrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.topScrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.topScrollView.addSubview(imgThree)
    self.topScrollView.addSubview(imgFour)
    self.topScrollView.addSubview(imgFive)

    self.topScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.topScrollView.frame.width * 5, height:self.topScrollView.frame.height)
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0

  }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1

    // Change the indicator
    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. Hope it helps someone else. I added:

```
@objc var imgOne = UIImageView()
@objc var imgTwo = UIImageView()
@objc var imgThree = UIImageView()
@objc var imgFour = UIImageView()
@objc var imgFive = UIImageView()

   @objc func imageTapped(_sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsMapsViewController") as! DetailsMapsViewController
     vc.restaurantMaps = self.restaurantArray[_sender.view!.tag]
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

    imgOne.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.imageTapped)))
    imgTwo.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.imageTapped)))
    imgThree.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.imageTapped)))
    imgFour.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.imageTapped)))
    imgFive.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.imageTapped)))

    imgOne.tag = 0
    imgTwo.tag = 1
    imgThree.tag = 2
    imgFour.tag = 3
    imgFive.tag = 4
```